# Sublime text split view, 2 columns on top, 1 column on bottom

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Can I do this with Sublime text?

[image]

Sublime Text split view, 2 columns on top, 1 column on bottom.

Comment: If you're asking about SublimeText, why is the question tagged [tag:vim] and [tag:macvim]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can type this in the ST Console (View menu -> Show Console):

```
window.set_layout({'cells': [[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2, 1], [0, 1, 2, 2]], 'rows': [0.0, 0.5, 1.0], 'cols': [0.0, 0.5, 1.0]})
```

There is a guide on how the layout works:

- https://nikolaloncar.com/sublime-text-custom-layout-tutorial-inside-out-with-examples/

And some plugins that make it easier to work with different layouts:

- https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Origami
- https://packagecontrol.io/packages/More%20Layouts